# Requesting user input from outside the GUI code, do I need Events or Action to communicate with the GUI in this case?

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener

I'm writing a 2D polygon and physics editor, one functionality is to set a rotation limit for joints.

To use this functionality, the user clicks and drags a line between the joint points which need to receive the limit.

The logic of determining if the pick is valid happens outside of the GUI code.

If a pick is found, I wanted to pop up a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` where the user can input the limit.

Thing is, if I do it directly, the program becomes unresponsive, I figure it's because of threading.

I's there a way to define an event listener the GUI can use that doesn't require an actual GUI component?

I want to send an event that also contains a reference to the target object to that component, then telling it that a valid pick has been made and user input is required, and then send the value back via a method of the target object.

I am very inexperienced with Swing.
My hunch is that I  might be able to add an `ActionListener` to the main window, but I don't know how I could address that listener specifically.
As in, how would I need to define an `Action` that only gets processed by that particular listener?
If that is actually possible, of course.

So far I have only used listeners to let the GUI talk to the logic, not the other way around...

Edit:
The program becomes unresponsive the movement I call 
 `result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Enter Limit.");`

That just breaks it. Can't even enter anything into the textbox, nor close it, etc.

I figure it's because it spawns a modal  dialog that pauses some thread, and calling it from somewhere in the bowels of non GUI code is just not the thing I should do, but I'm too inexperienced to know another way...

Edit2:
I should add that I can use JOptionPane.showInputDialog without any problems if I spawn it, for example, after clicking a button or choosing a popup menu option.
In fact that's how I rename  the items I am working with.

But I assume at that point, the dialog is being spawned inside the GUI thread, or this Event Dispatcher queue thing.

The problem with this though is, that this takes visible, interactive GUI components that fire that event.
What I'd like, however, is some sort of component that would spawn JOptionPane.showInputDialog just like a clicked button or context menu would, but without having to be interacted with by the user, but instead by the code.
I guess I could use invisible buttons and emulate mouseclick events, but that's pretty hacky...

Also, I tried spawning Threads and Runnables which spawned the JOptionPane.showInputDialog, but that didn't help either.
Unless I spawn the JOptionPane from a GUI source, everything stalls, and the dialog won't work.

Comment: So the sequence is 1) User clicks one point and drags to another 2) Model code determines if those two points define a joint 3) If so, UI shows a dialog asking for a number 4) When the dialog is closed, the model is updated and the UI repaints. Did I understand that correctly? At what phase is the UI becoming unresponsive?

Comment: @Russell Zahniser updated my post, not sure how much that clears up, but it really does just seem like a function call that doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible for your background thread to spawn a dialog with `invokeAndWait()`:

```
final double[] result = new double[1];
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      try {
         result[0] = Double.parseDouble(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value:"));
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
         result[0] = -1;
      }
   }
}
// ... do something with result[0]
```

Here I made the `result` an array just so that it can be final (accessible to the anonymous class) and also mutable.

Comment: invokeAndWait() didn't work, and oddly enough threw an exception and told me "Cannot Call invokeAndWait From The Event Dispatcher Thread". invokeLater, however, did work. Why that piece of code was considered a part of the Event Dispatcher thread, I do not know. I'm using Libgdx, and the glcanvas, which takes the application with the code as an argument, get's bound into a Swing component. That might be it. Ugh...Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The publisher will have a public add/remove listener, where the subscriber will add itself or be added via another channel to the EventListenerList in the publisher.

You can create your own listener interface that extends EventListener and a function to shoot an event. Below is an example:

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface MyEventListener extends EventListener {
   public void myEventOccurred(MyEvent event);
}
```

You can then create your custom event class, "MyEvent" in the example above like:

```
import java.util.EventObject;

public class MyEvent extends EventObject {
  // customer fields and methods here
  public MyEvent(Object source) //more possible args here {
    super(source);
    //other things here to do what you want
  }
}
```

Now you can have your subscriber implement MyEventListener and override the myEventOccurred(..) method.

Comment: How would I add MyEventListener to my  GUI? The main window class is a JFrame, and it lacks an addActionListener method...

Comment: So your publisher (the class that's sending the event) needs to contain public add and remove methods that take a MyEventListener as an argument.  The publisher then adds that listener to a list of type EventListenerList.  The subscriber (the class that needs to hear the event happen) needs to implement MyEventListener and add itself to the publisher list via that public add method. When the publisher needs to publish an event, it loops through it's subscribers and sends the event to each of them.

Comment: Hm, I just tried this, but in the end it seemed to have emulated a direct call to JOptionPane.showInputDialog, again. It seems the real problem I am having here is thread related. The non GUI code stalls when the input dialog is spawned, and the dialog itself becomes unusable, forcing me to kill the application from the outside. Imagine having written a game, and somewhere inside the physics integration you spawn a modal dialog that stalls everything, not just the GUI layer. That seems to be the culprit here.

Comment: updated the question, maybe it will provide some more clarification now.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use the SwingWorker class to execute the logic of determining the pick in a dedicated thread without blocking the GUI dispatch thread, and use its callback method to execute the GUI action (open the input dialog).

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

(This page has a better explanation of concept than I could write.)